# Opencv 3.1 compiled with FFMPEG, but won't open https urls

Tags: video, compiling, ffmpeg, opencv, gstreamer

I work on a 16.04 system, and have successfully installed opencv 3.1 with FFMPEG flags enabled. I double checked this was actually the case by cv2.getBuildInformation() and I got FFMPEG = YES.

I am trying to open a video that is hostel on a private server by my workplace (I am logged in to the VPN, in case thats a concern) and I can access this video over the browser. But videocapture with cv2 fails.

```
>>> cap = cv2.VideoCapture("https://xxx.mp4", cv2.CAP_ANY) #dummy url
>>> cap
<VideoCapture 0x7f63300fa4b0>
>>> cap.isOpened()
False
```

This is always the case for https urls. It seems to be able to work with local videos just fine.
I have tried a bunch of different thing: initially thought it was a gstreamer problem so I checked my plugins, had some gst-bad versions (ref: https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-ugly), removed those and replaced with good versions, no joy.
Also tried to explicitly tell videoCapture to use cv2.CAP_ANY and cv2.CAP_FFMPEG flags while reading the video, still no luck.

I disabled the Gstreamer flag while compiling opencv, but even with it set to ON, there was no difference in my problem.

I haven't been able to find a solution to this issue and have been looking and trying different things for days now! Any ideas?

Comment: Is it documented anywhere that it *should* work with a URI string? I only see mention of local files or video devices

Comment: Good point. But all my other colleagues at work are able to do this, so I can only assume that it is meant to work. I had been checking against their opencv builds to push mine towards working, which is what led me to the gstreamer and ffmpeg changes, but no luck there either.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually, I gave up on trying to install and reinstall opencv3.1, and switched to opencv 3.4.1. With that, and my current (as original question post) configuration for gstreamer and ffmpeg, I only had to create symlinks for libopencv_core.so.2.4 that gstreamer was looking for, and the rest of it worked fine.
Hope this helps someone!
I haven't managed to figure out what exactly was the issue with opencv3.1 (like I mentioned, that is the configuration my other colleagues have, and the functionality works just fine for them) but this is what I ended up doing after spending days on the issue.